# How do I disable touch swiping to return to the previous page

Tags: jxbrowser

In JavafX, swipe right returns the touch screen to the previous page, swipe left goes to the next page, I want to disable them

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it, This is Chromium Command Line Switches.

```
 BrowserPreferences.setChromiumSwitches(
            "--overscroll-history-navigation=0"
    );
```